# Cells not appearing when linking table view controller to table view file

Tags: ios, swift

Very new to iOS dev so a little help would be greatly appreciated !

Created a table view controller with static cells in it. If no swift file is linked to it, I can see the cells when building the app.

However, if I link a table view controller to it (which I believe I should?), I don't see the cells anymore. Why is that?

Thanks !

Comment: please add code and/or be more clear.. a lot more ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you have to keep in mind when using Table View.

First, you have to make sure you link the table view to your file by control dragging it from the main.storyboard to your view controller.

Second, you must make sure that the cell has an identifier. Make sure you select the cell and not the table and set the identifier to a certain name (for simple projects, we generally just use the identifier "cell")

Third, you have to make sure that the datasource (and usually the delegate) is set to the view controller. 
There are two ways of doing that, first, you can drag the table view to the View Controller icon (I believe it is the yellow one, but one of those on the top of your iOS screen storyboard), and select datasource and delegate. The second way is after you have referenced your table view to your view controller file, in the viewDidLoad method, set the table view's delegate and datasource to self. For instance, if your table view is named as tableView, the code should look something like

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Forth, make sure you include the following methods in your class. The numberOfRows, cellForRowAtIndexPath, and for numberOfSections, just return 1.

If everything still doesn't work, you can share us the code, maybe there are some other potential problems I forgot.